# Java can not read .p12 file stored in Oracle Blob column during Keystore initialization

Tags: java, oracle, blob

I am trying to perform *non-common* functionality using Java inside Oracle Database schema, but after several weeks I got stoned with weird java behavior.

### My desired functionality

I want to apply a digital signature over XML document (using pre-existing p12 certificate file) using Oracle PL/SQL procedures and Java classes stored in the same database schema (I am trying to avoid using external API/web services for the digital signature functionality).

### Context Info

This is a brief overview of the solution design:
 1. I want to use java classes stored in the same Oracle Database instance
 2. I want to call java classes from PL/SQL
 3. The main signature functionality will happen inside Java class which will connect to Oracle Database a get two Blob files: the digital certificate stored as p12 file inside one Blob column and the XML file to be signed stored in another Blob column.

### The problem

After several testing I detected a weird java behavior.  Java **can** read the Blob columns contents **without problem** (it can explore the size of the blob, print the contents, etc.)

But when I try to use a Blob column (the one which contains the p12 file) as an InputStream for the Keystore class, java can **not** load the certificate into the Keystore.

Here is a piece of code just to see if you have any ideas about **how to force the Keystore class** to read the contents of Blob as input...

```
public static String Blob_X509Cert_Test() {
    String v_hilera = null;
    try {
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
                          ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:15210:mysid",
                            "myuseraccount","mypassword");
         Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select blob_cert from tmp_blob");
         if (rs.next()) {
            Blob v_blob = rs.getBlob("blob_cert");
            InputStream v_is = v_blob.getBinaryStream();
            int v_b = v_is.read();
            KeyStore p12;
            try {
                 p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
                 try {
                      p12.load(v_is, "p12password".toCharArray());
                      Enumeration<String> e = p12.aliases();
                      while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                             String alias = (String) e.nextElement();
                             X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate)
                                                 p12.getCertificate(alias);
                             Principal subject = c.getSubjectDN();
                             String subjectArray[] =
                                        subject.toString().split(",");
                             for (String s : subjectArray) {
                                  String[] str = s.trim().split("=");
                                  String key = str[0];
                                  String value = str[1];
                             }
                 }
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }
         } catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return v_hilera;
}
```

This piece of code **could be incomplete** (I put it here just for help a conceptual understanding, but I am ready to share more code if necessary).

In my research, I isolete the problem to the Keystore.load() method which can not read the Blob contents (perhaps, the problem could be on another site).

If I use local file system as input stream for the Keystore.load() everything works as expected...

If you try this piece of code:

```
FileInputStream v_fis = new FileInputStream("C:/temp/TD_Cramos_Test.p12");
System.out.println("v_fis.available(): " + v_fis.available());
```

Result: **6736** (size of the file contents)

If you try same functionality but with **Blob** "file" the result will be **cero** bytes:

```
InputStream v_is = v_blob.getBinaryStream();
System.out.println("v_is.available(): " + v_is.available());
```

Result: **0** (for some reason, the blob contents is no read)

Any help or guidance will be really appreciated,

Carlos.

Comment: can you post the code again with proper indentation. It's hard to read this way.

Comment: Hi Lokesh, thanks for reading my post.  I improve the redaction, hope it helps.... Regards.

Comment: does this not throw any error ? Can you try converting your data into byt array and then store

Comment: No errors are thrown.....

Comment: Convert the Blob contents to byte array can not work because Keystore.load() requires the first parameter to be type "stream"

Comment: Lokesh, I edited the post, final lines contains two little examples to consider...  Thanks again....